# How to change embed src on onclick dynamically?

Tags: javascript, php

I would like a script that can change the `embed src` based on which link the user will click without loading the page.

```
<?php
    echo "<a href='http://google.com' onclick='javascript:void(0);' onclick='javascript:popWhenClicked(this.href);'>Google.com</a><br />";
    echo "<a href='http://bing.com' onclick='javascript:void(0);' onclick='javascript:popWhenClicked(this.href);'>Bing.com</a><br />";

    echo "<embed src='http://yahoo.com' width='700px' height='500px' />";
?>
```

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function popWhenClicked(href) {             
        document.getElementsByTagName("embed").setAttribute('src', 'href');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You mean without triggering the link on your main page?

Comment: No, I mean when the user clicks on the for example Google.com link. The embed src should be src='http://google.com' so embed will show Google instead of Yahoo.

Comment: you should merge your `onclick` attributes by the way, you're not supposed to have 2 of them; the `javascript:void(0);` should be removed and replaced by a `return false;` in your function, or something like `e.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

1) Remove the quotes `'` from your `setAttribute` function. The `href` is an *variable* passed as a parameter

2) In the `popWhenClicked` function and select the first element inside the object. The `getElementsByTagName` gets a list of elements matching the selector.

3) Don't assign the `onclick` multiple times, but use it only one time. Instead do a `return false` inside the `popWhenClicked` function.

So do it this way: (Click on *bing*, google throws an error)

```js
function popWhenClicked(href) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("embed")[0].setAttribute('src', href);

    // Prevent link from going to target
    return false;
}
```

```html
<a href='https://google.com' onclick='javascript:popWhenClicked(this.href);'>Google.com</a><br />
<a href='https://bing.com' onclick='javascript:popWhenClicked(this.href);'>Bing.com</a><br />
<embed src='https://yahoo.com' width='700px' height='500px' />
```

Comment: This doesn't seem enough. I mean, there's clearly a mistake there, but it's not the only problem, I guess.

Comment: Given OP's comment to the question, you also need to prevent the link from triggering, so return `false` or something.

Comment: Thanks for helping I know I am pretty close to the solution but, it's still going to the target :(